# How to determine if the kernel in a jupyter notebook continues running?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, kernel, svm

I am training a Support Vector Machine Classifier. It takes over 3 hours. Sometimes, I cannot determine if it is still running because even when I see Python running in the Task Manager, my cooler is stopping to make noise.

Comment: I would use "Task Manager" to see CPU usage, or `htop` if you're on mac/linux.

Comment: Also, there are probably ways to make any ML algorithm to be verbose about it's progress. If you can't figure that out - just put global level of logging to `DEBUG` to start with. `import logging; logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`